# App not showing in search on chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

App not showing in search on chrome web store.
It is published (more than 2 weeks ago), but if I search for it with keywords it is not showing up in any of the results.

Comment: Are you on Chrome OS?

Comment: No, app for Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome apps have been deprecated except on Chrome OS. You can continue using the same codebase with NW.js, but you will need to distribute to those platforms another way.

https://nwjs.io/blog/chrome-apps-support/

https://nwjs.io/blog/whats-new-in-0.13/

"Starting in late 2016, newly-published Chrome apps will only be available to users on Chrome OS. Existing Chrome apps will remain accessible on all platforms, and developers can continue to update them.
In the second half of 2017, the Chrome Web Store will no longer show Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but will continue to surface extensions and themes. In early 2018, users on these platforms will no longer be able to load Chrome apps.

https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html

Comment: that sucks, I downloaded an editor that I really like that runs atop of chrome